# Angularstrap - modal box

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I am using rails to build my app. Tried to popup a modal box with angularstrap http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modal they are giving example of using modal box with partials.But I want to call a div from same page.they mention something with ng-template.But I didn't get any documentation for that. Anybody know about this??

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about `ng-template` [here in the AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ascript). Implement it as follows:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal-template.html">
     <div>Content of Modal</div>
</script>
```

Then where you're calling the modal, replace the reference to the partial with `modal-template.html`:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" bs-modal="'modal-template.html'">Call to Action</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the main html page define your TemplageCache as follows:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" class="modal" id="/myTmpl.html">
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" ng-click="$hide()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">This title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  This is content
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$hide()">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then in javascript

```
$scope.showMyModal=function(){
    var myModal = $modal({placement:'center', animation:"am-fade-and-scale", templateUrl:'/myTmpl.html', show: true});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for working so hard to get the code indented properly! Instead of using `&nbsp;`, you can actually get code formatted in a code block by clicking the button that looks like two curly braces.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely learn and use the tools SO is providing.

Answer (score 0):

An ng-template would be if you had a inline (html string in javascript) variable. For example:

```
var t = "<div></div>";
```

t could be your ng-template.

Unforunately I don't know how to do what you are looking for.